# How many ways are there to arrange 4n people around a square table if the 4 cyclic shifts around the table constitute the same seating?

Tags: combinatorics

I got $$4n!/4,$$ but I think $$4n!/4n$$ might be the real answer. Also could you explain why? I know the division rule is what is being tested here.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, that is clearly wrong, as it is just $n!$

Comment: Yes, thank you, wrong parentheses!

Answer (score 3):

The total number of ways to line people up in a row is $(4n)!$.

I guess we're then assuming that each side of the table is going to have $n$ people, so each of these arrangements gives us 4 cyclic shifts, so you need simply to divide by 4 (as you originally thought).

So the answer is $(4n)!/4$.